# switching to payments pro while still running payments standard?

Tags: paypal

I am currently using paypal payments standard and i am in the process of switching to pro.

I can not take down the standard payment page (both pages will be hosted on paypal), until the pro version is ready to go as we are constantly taking payments.

I cant seem to find any information on if I can test and play with payments pro without affecting what the users see on the live payments standard page. Is it a different URL that the pages each go to? Or is a case of having to put the pro version live when I am ready? I cant really see any buttons on paypal that explicitly say switch/go live etc.

THanks in advance

Nadeem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the sandbox. The sandbox is an exact replica of the live paypal system except that it is used for developing and testing paypal dependent application.

See https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/access.html

Comment: Hi Rijndael, Thanks for the answer, Im aware of the sandbox, its more a worry of if i start playing around things in pro, where the users will be directed to on the standard version, is it a case of after testing i turn the pro version on? I cant see anything that distinguishes on the live site whether I am using payment pro or payment standard,.

Comment: Well, you should have a development environment to manage that. Once the pro feature is complete and tested on dev/staging enviroment then it is only a matter of deploying it to your production server. In such a context the transition will be seamless and you don't need to worry about the payment breaking on production or users seeing things they should not be seeing. NEVER try out or build features directly on a production server.